# Why is lucreate failing to create a bootable image?

Tags: solaris, sunos

I am attempting to make a Solaris 8 bootable drive from a *flar* image following [these instructions from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/821-1910/luexample-28.html#).

The command:

```
lucreate -s - -m /:/dev/dsk/c1t1d0s0:ufs \ -n second_disk
```

fails with a command line error. Trying again without the \, the command:

```
lucreate -s - -m /:/dev/dsk/c1t1d0s0:ufs -n second_disk
```

fails with the error message:

> luconfig: ERROR: Template filesystem definition failed for /.. ERROR:
>   Configuration of BE failed.

I found [this in a page on the Oracle website](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/821-2729/gdsqk.html) on upgrade issues:

> Zones Are Not in the Running State (7055968)
>
> If you run the lucreate or the lumake command on a system running
>   Trusted Extensions, the commands might fail if the system has labeled
>   non-global zones and the zones are not in running state.

and the workaround says to:

> Workaround: Ensure that all non-global zones are in the running state
>   before using the lucreate and lumake commands.

But I am not sure that non-global zones are the issue. We are using *ufs*, not *zfs*, and I cannot find the zone administrations commands (*zonecfg*, *zoneadmin*) on this system.

I would like to understand how to make this work. Is the issue that there is a *non-global* zone on this system? How do I find out without zone administration commands? Is there something else I need to do before I run *lucreate*?

My system is a Sun-Fire-V210 (sparc) running SunOS 5.8 (which I believe is the same as Solaris 8).

Comment: Do you have a Sun Fire V210 server? OS Solaris 5.8 (Solaris 8)? `$ uname -rs
SunOS 5.8`

Answer (score 0):

[install the boot block on a UFS root file system](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-5093/6mkisoq7l/index.html) 
Example 1.

```
bash-2.03# format
Searching for disks...done


AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
       0. c1t0d0 <SUN72G cyl 14087 alt 2 hd 24 sec 424>
          /pci@1f,700000/scsi@2/sd@0,0
       1. c1t1d0 <SUN72G cyl 14087 alt 2 hd 24 sec 424>
          /pci@1f,700000/scsi@2/sd@1,0
Specify disk (enter its number):

partition> p
Current partition table (original):
Total disk cylinders available: 14087 + 2 (reserved cylinders)

Part      Tag    Flag     Cylinders         Size            Blocks
  0       root    wm       0 - 11874       57.62GB    (11875/0/0) 120840000
  1       swap    wu   11875 - 12680        3.91GB    (806/0/0)     8201856
  2     backup    wm       0 - 14086       68.35GB    (14087/0/0) 143349312
  3 unassigned    wu       0                0         (0/0/0)             0
  4 unassigned    wu       0                0         (0/0/0)             0
  5 unassigned    wu       0                0         (0/0/0)             0
  6 unassigned    wm   12681 - 12683       14.91MB    (3/0/0)         30528
  7 unassigned    wu       0                0         (0/0/0)             0

partition>
```

install the boot block on a UFS root partition S0 on second disk c1t1d0

```
    #installboot /usr/platform/sun4u/lib/fs/ufs/bootblk /dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s0
```